# How to format dynamically generated HTML with django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to create a sheet of labels to print out with a QR code a logo and phone number, the QR codes are generated separately from an `xlsx` file and they work. My issue is formatting them in the HTML. I'm not sure how to change the for loop so it creates a row for each time an image is loaded onto the label.
here's the html part of the code:

```
 {% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>labels</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}"/>
<table width="150" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
            {% for item in list_qr_images %}
                <img src="{% static 'inc.png' %}" align="center"/>
                <img src="{{ item }}" align="center">
                <p style="text-align:left">(718) 280-0000</p>
            {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
</br>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the the `tr` start and end tag inside the loop?

Comment: I have tried that , but it creates only one row with all the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error i figured out the issues. Heres the code formatted to fix and Avery 61523 sheet in case anyone might find it useful in the future.

```
    {% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>labels</title>
    <style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:3 0 0 0 1 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-469750017 -1073732485 9 0 511 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:8.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:107%;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
.MsoPapDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    margin-bottom:8.0pt;
    line-height:107%;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:.55in .3in 3in .55in;
    mso-header-margin:.1in;
    mso-footer-margin:.12in;
    mso-paper-source:4;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
    </style>
    <xml>
        <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026"/>
    </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
            <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
        </o:shapelayout>
    </xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}"/>
<table class=MsoTableGrid border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
       style='margin-left:-.75pt;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-padding-top-alt: 0in;mso-padding-bottom-alt:0in;mso-border-insideh:none;mso-border-insidev: none'>

    {% for item in list_qr_images %}
    <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;page-break-inside:avoid; height:47.5pt'>
            <img src="static/images/0'qr.jpg" align="center" style=" padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
</br>
</html>
```

I used word to generate a label page and then converted it into HTML format and edited it into the sized needed.